# '50s-'60s short: hero "plays the stats" to survive. Elites use electrical stimulation to have perfect bodies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This short story was in a paperback anthology read by my Dad, a sci-fi buff since the '40s. The lower class hero in a dystopian future scrapes out a living using his wits "playing the stats," which is a huge raw feed of economic data much like stock market info. He wants to join the upper class who have perfect bodies developed by painful electrical stimulation of their muscles. Eventually, he challenges a leader to a match at one of many elite games. Turns out the leader also "plays the stats," so they go at it.   ...This story influenced my life...

Many thanks to Leif Carlsen for the super-fast find. My Dad was a fan of Laumer. The Retief series was great as well!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Have you taken the [tour] yet? If your question has been answered, you can click on the checkmark next to the answer to accept that answer. This rewards the answerer and shows other users that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

You've described Keith Laumer's [Of Death What Dreams](http://atebook.net/book/33401).
He breaks into the undercity, takes a job running bets for bookies, convinces his boss to front him other people's money for some bets.

> I've worked out the major cycles, and enough minor ones to show a profit. It wasn't too hard. I minored in statan, back in my kid days.

At making some cash on this line, he breaks back into the city proper, pays for body building therapy and (hypnotic?) skill training.

> In the third week Bailey, out of the tank for his alter-hourly session in the treadcage, paused to look at himself in the mirror. His face was gaunt, knobbed below the jawline with unfamiliar lumps of muscle; his neck was awkwardly corded; his shoulders swelled in sinewy striations above a chest which seemed to belong to someone else.
>
> "I look wrong," he said. "Misshapen. No symmetry. Out of balance."
>
> "Sure, sure. What do you expect, to start with? Some sectors respond quicker, some were in better shape. Don't worry. First we go for tone, then bulk, then definition, then balance. You're doing swell. We start coordination and dynamics next. Another sixty days and you'll look like you were born under that blue tag."

He eventually confronts the upper class in a game of chance.

> The private game room to which Lord Tace conducted Bailey and the Apollo members contrasted sharply with the blighted cold-water flat from which Gus Aroon had rolled his book three months before; but the mathematics of the game were unchanged.